# Indefinite Integration (1) $ \int 2^{\log_{e}(x)}dx$ (2) $\int 2^{mx}\cdot 3^{nx}dx$

Tags: calculus

calculation of some Indefinite Integration

(1) $\displaystyle \int 2^{\log_{e}(x)}dx$

(2) $\displaystyle \int 2^{mx}\cdot 3^{nx}dx$

$\bf{My\; Try}::$ for (1) $\log_{e}(x)=t\Rightarrow x=e^t$ and $dx = e^tdt$

$\displaystyle \int 2^t\cdot e^t dt = \int (2e)^tdt = \frac{(2e)^t}{\log_{e}(2e)}+C$

My Question is can we solve it without using Substution

Similarly How can I solve it Directly Means without using Integration by parts,

Help Required

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For number (1), try using

$$2^{\ln{x}} = \left(e^{\ln{2}}\right)^{\ln{x}} = \left(e^{\ln{x}}\right)^{\ln{2}} = x^{\ln{2}}$$

and use the power rule.

Likewise for (2), start by writing $$2^{mx} = e^{(m\ln{2})x}$$ and $$3^{nx} = e^{(n \ln{3})x}$$